# Image Sliding background content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my site similar to http://allfiredupinc.com/ so when you slide down it doesn't show the background, it then shows the content. Also when you scroll up it shows the background.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CIsh.png]

```
body {
        background: url("http://uploadir.com/u/j027zo9j") no-repeat top center fixed;
        background-size: cover; 
}
```

How could I go about adding content like that? With the nice little effect it shows?

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin-top` to your content container, so if your content container has an ID `#main-content` you give it this style:

```
#main-content {
    /* Adjust this value as you want */
    margin-top: 30em;
    /* Other properties */
    ...
}
```